# Expand/Collapse Array of cells in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I would like to expand and collapse an array of cells in my uitableview by clicking on a button on a cell. I dont want to expand or collapse the cell on which I click but the subsequent child cells. Also, I want to expand and collapse only those items in the arrays.

Currently, I have the following code but it doesnot do anything regards to updating the cells.

What am I doing wrong ?

```
- (void)reloadTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSArray *itemsArray = self.childItems;

    NSMutableArray *insertPath = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *deletePath = [NSMutableArray array];

    [itemsArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if (![itemsArray containsObject:obj]) {
            [insertPath addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:idx inSection:0]];
        }
    }];

    [itemsArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([itemsArray containsObject:obj]) {
            [deletePath addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:idx inSection:0]];
        }
    }];

    if ([insertPath count] || [deletePath count]) {
        [tableView beginUpdates];

        if ([deletePath count]) {
            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:deletePath withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }

        if ([insertPath count]) {
            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:insertPath withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }
        [tableView endUpdates];
    }
    else {
        [tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only reloading the rows you wish to delete or insert. Instead, delete the rows to delete and insert the rows to insert.

```
[tableView beginUpdates];

if ([deletePath count]) {
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deletePath withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}

if ([insertPath count]) {
    [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertPath withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: thanks maddy...but I always get Invalid number of rows in section.

Comment: You need to update your table view's data source before updating the table view.

Comment: do you mean add removeObjectAtIndex ?

Comment: I mean the array (or whatever) you use in your `numberOfRowsInSection` and other data source methods. You need to update those data structures.